# How to read data from DataGrid of one usercontrol in another

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

i am new to wpf. this is my oneUserControl in which i have a data grid.

```
   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TraceMessages}" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    CanUserReorderColumns="True" 
                    CanUserSortColumns="True">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Severity" Binding="{Binding Path=Severity}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Context" Width="300" Binding="{Binding Path=Context}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Correlation Id" Binding="{Binding Path=CorrelationId}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Message Body" Width="600" Binding="{Binding Path=Data}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

i have another usercontrol of which viewmodel i need to access data from above datagrid.how to do it
?

Answer (score 0):

If you have another ViewModel in your View's ViewModel you could do this after you create your 2 VMs. This will sincronize your first VM with your second VM after any of the properties you set in the `OnYourFirstVMPropertyChanged` method change:

```
public class YourVMDataSource
{
    #region Attributes

    private readonly YourFirstVM yourFirstVM;
    private readonly YourSecondVM yourSecondVM;

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    public NumeracionFacturasDisponiblesVMDataSource(YourFirstVM yourFirstVM, YourSecondVM yourSecondVM)
    {
        this.yourFirstVM = yourFirstVM;
        this.yourSecondVM = yourSecondVM;
    }


    public void Initialize()
    {
        this.yourFirstVM.PropertyChanged += this.OnYourFirstVMPropertyChanged;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Event Handlers

    private void OnYourFirstVMPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        YourFirstVM yourFirstVMSender = (YourFirstVM) sender;
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case "WhateverPropertyYouWantToSincronize":
                 this.YourSecondVM.PropertyYouWantToGet = sender. WhateverPropertyYouWantToSincronize;
                 break;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Feel free to ask again if you don't get it.

Comment: how to read data from grid, i need that particular line. there will be thousands of rows.

Comment: Like I posted, if you do that with your “source” vm which populates the grid and the vm you need to read it, the second VM will have whatever you place there. Look my edit on the propertychanged event. Try this and let me know what happens :)